# I'm trying to do a statistical analysis of 900,00+ rows in 1 Column. I'm having a few issues

Tags: r

I've imported the dataset, assigned it as a data frame, and now I'm lost. I'm looking to find the mean and median (already found) and mode. I'm having trouble finding the mode. I've tried different [Modeest library](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modeest) functions and was hoping `mlv`. would do it. All I got back was

```
Error in mlv.default (___) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

I've also converted it to numeric as well (I think) by using

```
as.numeric(as.character(dataset$column name))
```

I'm not even sure if that was necessary and if my column is already a value/object.

Honestly, I'm lost, tired, and frustrated.

I also need to find the variance and standard deviation. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data with `dput(head(your_dataset))`?

Comment: For mode, you can use this `rev(table(dataset$column_name))[1]` . For variance and sd, if you can calculate mean, you could calculate them.